# Rectangle.java:35: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

When I try to compile this code I get an error saying 
"
Rectangle.java:35: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
        this.inDemand = inDemand;
"
I found a workaround by renaming the inDemand argument to isInDemand and removing the this prefix from inDemand in the setInDemand method. I am just trying to understand why what I was doing initially didn't work.

The code is below:

```
public class Rectangle extends Polygon
{
    private double height;
    private static boolean inDemand = false;
    private double width;
    public Rectangle()
    {
        this(1,1,"None");
    }
    public Rectangle(double height, double width, String id)
    {
        super(id);
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public double getArea()
    {
        return this.height*this.width;
    }

    public double getTotal()
    {
        if(inDemand == true)
        {
            return 2 * this.getArea();
        }
        else
        {
            return this.getArea();
        }
    }
    public static void setInDemand(boolean inDemand)
    {
        this.inDemand = inDemand;
    }




    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.setInDemand(true);
        System.out.println(rect.getTotal());
    }


}
```

Comment: The program I am making will have multiple objects of type rectangle. The property of being "inDemand" is held by the class not by the object. If rectangles are in demand I want all rectangle objects to be in demand.

Comment: Also, thanks for the help everyone, basically what I gathered from all the comments was that the "this" prefix refers to the instantiated object which isn't static. Thus putting "this" in front of a static variable isn't correct. What I did was I used the name of the class instead like this:


    Rectangle.inDemand = inDemand;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public static void setInDemand(boolean inDemand)
    {
        this.inDemand = inDemand;
    }
```

`this` is not allowed in `static` methods as it refers to the current object. Assume a scenario when you call this method in a static way without creating an instance. Here is what i mean:

```
Rectangle.setInDemand(true);
```

is a legal call to this method but not on an instance rather using the class name.

Comment: Using the name of the class as a prefix worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`inDemand` is declared to be a `static` field.  Any field or method with that declaration can only be referenced in a static context.

The simplest thing to do would be to remove `static` from that boolean and method signature, since its usage suggests it's a property of the object `Rectangle`.

You would declare a field or a method `static` if and only if it didn't need to be a property of the class itself, but held information about the class (i.e. `Integer.MAX_VALUE`), or could be used to produce a an instance of that object (i.e. `Integer.valueOf(2)`).

Comment: thanks for the answer, in this current situation inDemand actually needs to be static because it is a property of all rectangles. Is there a method of specifying the variable similar to how it's done with the this prefix that works with static variables?

Comment: That seems counter-intuitive to me, but removing `this` would probably do it.

Answer (score 1):

this referes to the currently executing object. static methods are not part of object, they are part of class. So you cannot reference currently executing object using static methods

Remove static modifier for the field

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.inDemand as *this* means doing an operation on the current object. As it is static, you do not have an object instantiated.